# Strange groovy behavior when dealing with threads

Tags: groovy

I have an interesting dilemma.

If I define my class as:

```
 class Browser {
      def swtException
      protected Object evaluate(script) throws SWTException {
         swtException=null
         display.syncExec() {
         try {
         result=swtBrowser.evaluate(script)
         } catch (SWTException swtException) {
         Browser.swtException=swtException
         }
      }
 }
```

I get this rather interesting error:

Exception in thread "Thread-5" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: swtException for class
: com.mksoft.fbautomate.browser.Browser
Possible solutions: swtException)

Any ideas???

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are trying to access a attribute of a class in a static way? you seem to refer to `Browser.swtException` but `Browser` is a class, not an object instance.

You should declare `swtException` as `static` or use `this.browser` to access the one of your current object.